# Handling an array of pointers

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm attempting to create a struct that has an array of char pointers as one of its members and am having trouble attempting to set/access elements of the array. Each char pointer is going to point to a malloc'd buffer. This is the struct currently.

```
struct rt_args {
    long threadId;
    char (*buffers)[];
    FILE* threadFP;
};
```

And when I attempt to access an element of buffers via

```
char *buffer = malloc(100);

struct rt_args (*rThreadArgs) =  malloc( sizeof(long) + 
                                         (sizeof(char *) * (numThreads)) +
                                         sizeof(FILE*)
                                 );
rThreadArgs->buffers[0] = buffer;
```

I get the error "invalid use of array with unspecified bounds". I don't know what the size of the array is going to be beforehand, so I can't hardcode its size. (I've tried de-referencing buffers[0] and and adding a second index? I feel as though its a syntactical error I'm making)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have arrays without a size, just like the error message says, at least not n the middle of structures. In your case you might think about pointers to pointers to `char`? Then you can use e.g. `malloc` for the initial array and `realloc` when needed.

Something like

```
char **buffers;
```

Then do

```
buffers = malloc(sizeof(buffers[0]) * number_of_pointers_needed);
```

Then you can use `buffers` like a "normal" array of pointers:

```
buffers[0] = malloc(length_of_string + 1);
strcpy(buffers[0], some_string);
```

Comment: Please excuse, the declaration of `struct rt_args` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @alk Not with a flexible array (array without a size). Those has to be placed last in the structure, so when not being last the structure is not valid.

Comment: `char (*buffers)[];` isn't a "*flexible array*" but a pointer to one.

Comment: @alk Yes, but it's not what the OP wants, if we read the question and its title.

Answer (score 0):

```
char (*buffers)[SIZE];
```

declares `buffers` as a pointer to `char` array not the array of pointers. I think you need this

```
char *buffers[SIZE];
```

**NOTE:** *Flexible array member can be used only when it is the last member of the structure.*

Comment: What if I don't know the size of the array? It will depend on input.

Comment: If you are using flexible array member then it must be a last member and you need to allocate space, depends on your input, for it before using it.

Comment: Why exactly would you need it to be the last member? I don't think that that would be required... It's just a pointer.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin; Flexible array members are must be a last member of a structure.